# How do I remove or skip lines of code after every single loop a do-while loop does?

Tags: java

This code is for a little minigame I am trying to create.

CARDS is an object (I have 8 in total (4 per player)) each individual card is being randomly generated upon starting the game, ***but I cannot think of a way to prevent cards that have already been chosen to stop appearing.***

I want to remove those options (those which both players chose) after the loop.

```
do {
    //options for the player
    System.out.printl(card1.getNum() + card1.getDesign);
    System.out.printl(card2.getNum() + card2.getDesign);
    System.out.printl(card3.getNum() + card3.getDesign);

    //choosing a card
    int chosenCardp1 = scanner.nextInt();
    int chosenCardp2 = scanner.nextInt();
    
    // calculations and point awarding (a bunch of if and if else statements)
} while (pointsP1 < 3 && pointsP2 < 3);
```

Comment: Add the cards to an `ArrayList` beforehand, and remove them one-by-one?

Comment: I will try this right now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "List of cards" with all the cards initialized inside, and once they are chosen from the scanner or randomly selected you can remove them from the list. But this requires that the selection of cards happens from the collection you created.

```
List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
Card card1 = new Card();
card1.setNum = 1;
card1.setDesign = "king"

cards.add (card1);
```

or with java streams and a constructor

```
class Card{
 int num;
 String design;

 public Card(int num, String design){
 this.num = num;
 this.design = design;
 }
}
```

Then

```
List<Card cards = Stream.of(new Card(5,"heart"),new Card(10,"spades")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```